# C# HTTP Socket File POST?

Tags: c#, file, http, sockets, post

I want to Upload a File over HTTP to a PHP Script, and i want to do it over Sockets. The Post is already working fine only the file does not seem to send properly.

At First i build up my HTTP Request till the start of the File, then i convert this string into a ByteArray. And with `Buffer.BlockCopy` i put the File at the end of this Array. And with another BlockCopy i put the end boundary at the end of the Array. After this i try to send my ByteArray as Request (with header), but it looks like the File does not send, or is the wrong format.

Here is some Part of my Code:

```
 _content = _content
      + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine
      + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + this._FileVarName + "\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(this._FilePath) + "\""
      + Environment.NewLine + "Content-Transfer-Encoding: application/octet-stream"
      + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

    mainContent = this.Combine(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_content), System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(this._FilePath));
    mainContent = this.Combine(mainContent, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + "--"));

    private byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
      byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
      Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
      Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
      return ret;
    }
```

Does anyone know this problem and could help me?

Comment: Why not use the `WebClient` class (see `UploadData` method) or at least `HttpWebRequest` class?

Comment: Because i want to do it over Sockets and want to avoid WebClient and HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Then continue to try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for these helpfull comments. It's somewhat a prebuild for a lowlevel C++ HTTP Class, it doesn't have anything to do with "reinventing the wheel", it's training.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you reading your file into your post? From what I remember, the actual attachment has to be Base64Encoded and limited to 65 characters per line?

Comment: These Restrictions should be for E-Mail Mime (if i remember right), when i check a FilePost Request with Firebug it shows the filedata in RAW-Format.

Comment: have you compared the output of your program with what a browser sends?